# Merge legend in ggplot when the geoms are different

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which yields the figure below:

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=x, y=y, mass=mass)) + 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, linetype='Gompertz predicted mass', col='Gompertz predicted mass')) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=x, y=mass, shape='Actual mass',col='Actual mass')) +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab('Mass') +
  xlab('t') +
  scale_color_manual(name='',values = c("black",'red')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name='',values = c("solid")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name='', values = c(19)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(4,26,2)) +
  ylim(c(0, 20000)) +
  ggtitle('Problem 3: Plot of tumor mass with time')
```

[image]

Notice how the legend is separated. I'd like to merge it for shape and color. When the `geoms` are the same, the technique of using `scale_something_manual` works perfectly fine to merge the legends. However, I'm having trouble with it here since I have two different `geoms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one described in https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3648. There is no elegant solution at the moment. Because you haven't included any data, I've presumed that your problem is conceptually similar to the plot below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "Point", colour = "Point")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Line", colour = "Line"),
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, method = "loess") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = "solid") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 19)
```

[image]

The way to fix the problem is to get rid of the linetype and shape aesthetics and scales, and instead override aesthetics at the level of the legend.

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = "Point")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "Line"),
              formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE, method = "loess") +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("red", "black"),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA, 19),
                                             linetype = c(1, NA)))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>